# BackgroundImage shifts when mouse cursor is hovering over the button

Tags: c#, winforms

Sorry for my english. This is the first time I write a question in this language. I will be glad if you correct my grammatical errors.

I create a `changing_button` and set its BackgroundImage property. I wanted this image to change when cursor is over this button. I made two pictures for that.

**blue_image.png:** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0tCW.png)

**red_image.png:** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av7ll.png)

Normally `changing_button` should display red_image. But if cursor is over this button, it should display blue_image. The problem is that blue_image shifts when I try to override BackgroundImage property: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z4IP.png)

How can I fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace winforms_test_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button changing_button;

        Image blue_image = Image.FromFile("D://images//blue_image.png");
        Image red_image = Image.FromFile("D://images//red_image.png");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TableLayoutPanel main_panel = new TableLayoutPanel
            {
                BackColor = Color.White,
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            };

            changing_button = new Button
            {
                BackgroundImage = red_image,
                BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center,
                FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
                Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0),
                Size = new Size(50, 50),
            };
            changing_button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            changing_button.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.test_button_MouseEnter);
            changing_button.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.test_button_MouseLeave);

            main_panel.Controls.Add(changing_button, 0, 0);
            Controls.Add(main_panel);
        }

        void test_button_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            changing_button.Image = blue_image;

        }

        void test_button_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            changing_button.Image = red_image;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your two images are **exactly** the same size?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Both images are 50*50px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the background image, set the initial Image to the red image. BackgroundImage and Image look like they have slightly different positions.

```
changing_button = new Button
{
    Image = red_image,
    ImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center,
    FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
    Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0),
    Size = new Size(50, 50),
};
```

Use either BackgroundImage or Image, but not both.

Comment: The different properties just do different things, that's all. background image is behind the main image. So you were telling the button to always have a red background, but sometimes show blue on top of the red. The red button also had the weird pixel offset, it just wasn't noticeable because it was a red button on a red background. In the end, it is easier to just switch the button between red and blue and leave the background alone